# Laravel migrations do not reflect the current database schema

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, migration

I'm working with an app in Laravel / MySQL that does not have all its tables defined through the migrations, because at one point they stopped using the migrations and made changes directly by touching the database. This makes that if I run a php artisan migrate do not take the current DB schema. My question is, do I have any way to reuse migrations from the current structure of the DB? If there is any procedure that updates me the migrations including those fields that were added directly in the table in the database.

Comment: There's nothing automatic in Laravel than can detect that. You'll likely have to go through the database, compare and adjust the initial migrations to match the current state of the database. There are instances when updating the database is simply easier then running a new migration (such as updating values in an `enum` column), so this can happen. But it's up to the person doing it to also adjust the migrations (even if they aren't being run/re-run right away).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick search brings me to a package, [cethron/migrations-generator](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator) (last update Sep 19, 2017). It generates migrations from existing databases. [Here](https://laraveldaily.com/review-3-tools-generate-laravel-migrations-existing-database/) is another article about some tools.

However you can still make new migrations. These migrations would either create new tables or alter the columns.

You should manually track down the difference and [modify the columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#modifying-columns).

```php
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('name', 50)->change();
});
```